# How to get all active parameters in ASP.NET MVC (2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was wondering whether there is a way to create an `ActionLink` or similar, that changes only a few parameters of the actual query, and keeps all the other parameters intact. For example if I'm on an URL like `http://example.com/Posts/Index?Page=5&OrderBy=Name&OrderDesc=True` I want to change only the `Page`, or `OrderBy` parameter and keep all other parameters the same, even those I don't yet know of (like when I want to add a `Search` parameter or something similar too).

The header of my current action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Page, string OrderBy, bool? Desc)
```

and I'm only interested in the values that this controller "eats". I want however that when I extend this action (for example with a `string Search` parameter) the links should work the same way as before.

Here is what I did already:

1. Create a new `RouteValueDictionary` and fill it with everything from `RouteData.Values`

   - Problem: This only fills the parameters that are used in the Routing, so all other optional parameters (like `Page`) to the controller are lost
2. Add everything from `HttpContext.Request.QueryString` to the previous dictionary

   - This is what I am currently using
   - Problem: It might have some junk stuff, that the Controller didn`t ask for, and it doesn't work if the page was loaded using POST. You also don't have any ModelBindings (but this isn't much of a problem, because we are re-sending everything anyway)
3. Use `HttpContext.Request.Params`

   - Problem: this has too much junk data which imho one shouldn't add to a `RouteValueDictionary` that is passed to an `ActionLink`

So the questions:

1. Is there an `RVD` that has all the data that was passed to the Controller and was used by it?
2. Is this solution good, or are there any caveats I didn't think about (mainly in the context of changing a few query parameters while keeping the others intact)?
3. Is there a way to filter out the "junk" data from the `Params` object?

EDIT: Checked the `RouteData.DataTokens` variable, but it's usually empty, and doesn't contain everything I need. It seems to only contain parameters that are needed for the routing somewhere, but not all of the parameters.

Comment: Have you looked in the `RouteData.DataTokens` dictionary? They might be in there... If they are I'll repost as an answer.

Comment: @Charlino: That's where they should be.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.datatokens.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Interesting that you find `area` in DataTokens becuase I would've thought it was used to find a matching route.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look in `RouteData.DataTokens`.

[RouteData.DataTokens @ MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.datatokens.aspx):

> Gets a collection of custom values that are passed to the route handler but are not used when ASP.NET routing determines whether the route matches a request.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: For me the Viewcontext.RouteData.DataTokens property is empty (Count==0), unless I define a route that needs some of the information I provided, but that's not my point. Seems these parameters aren't passed to the route handlers.

Comment: This is still giving me issues. I have a URL like Source?investigationKey=2. From the RouteData.Values I can only get the controller and the action. I don't get "investigationKey" anywhere.

Did anyone figure out how to get this?